# Solid Border-left with weird behavior on IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, border

I created a left border in a table header with CSS using the properties bellow that is working just how I desired on Chrome, but have a bad result/rendenring on IE, leaving the border area and having a weird sharp edge on the top.

```
th {
 border-left: 15px solid black;
 color: black;
 text-align: right;
 vertical-align: top; }
```

This is the result I'm getting on Chrome (and the desired one):

[border on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41OmK.png)

This is the result I'm getting in IE:

[border on IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPVR4.png)

[This is the showing of other border (painted from white to grey)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsVrk.png)

EDIT: I could find out that there is the influence of other borders, but on Chrome, the overlaps fits the one I desire. How can I make the border from other elements to overlap/bring-to-front my black border?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML? It looks like maybe IE is rendering more borders than just the left. Can you try killing off all borders and then applying only the left? So: `border: 0`, then `border-left: 15px solid black`...?

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, Donkey. I could find out that there is influence of other borders. Can you check the edit?

Comment: I think we can get to the bottom of it, but I'll need to see the relevant HTML code as well. Can you link to your project or include a code snippet? [</>]

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).